# On solvable octic trinomials like $x^8-5x-5=0$

Tags: galois-theory, radicals

Solvable quintic trinomials
$$x^5+ax+b=0$$
have been completely parameterized. Finding $6$th-deg versions is relatively easy to do such as,
$$x^6+3x+3=0$$
which factors over $\sqrt{-3}$. No $7$th-deg are known, but surprisingly there are ***octic*** ones, such as the simple,
$$x^8-5x-5=0$$
which factors over $\sqrt{5}$. And the not-so-simple ones,

$$x^8-11(4x+3)=0\\x^8+16(4x+7)=0\\x^8 + 5\cdot23^2(12 x+43) =0$$

which factors over a *quartic* extension (and needs the cube root of unity).

> **Q:** Any other octic examples, if possible parametric?

---

$\color{green}{Update:}$

Klajok in his answer below has found a family for the class of octic trinomials that factor over a quadratic extension. However, another class needs a *quartic* extension. For example,
$$x^8-44x-33=0\tag1$$
which factors into four quadratics,
$$x^2 + v x - (2v^3 - 7v^2 + 5v + 33)/13=0$$
and where $v$ is any root of $v^4 + 22v + 22=0$. More generally, eliminating $v$ between
$$x^2 + v x + (pv^3 +qv^2 + rv + s)=0$$
$$v^4+av^2+bv+c=0$$
easily done by the resultant function of *Mathematica* will result in an irreducible but solvable octic and judicious choice of rational coefficients will yield a trinomial. However, it is not known if this second class of trinomials like $(1)$ has a parametric family as well.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: I just saw your deleted example. It had ***six*** non-zero terms. A "trinomial" means it must have only three terms. Specifically, the post looks for $x^8+ax+b = 0$.

Comment: Sorry want paying attention to that constraint. @TitoPiezasIII  just a question though, you can actually see answers once they are deleted?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: Yes, special privileges once you get above a certain rep.  :)

Comment: The reference for the quintic is: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975165

Comment: @KentaS Thanks, yes, I've read their paper. The [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Roots_of_a_solvable_quintic) of the trinomial quintic $x^5-5x+12$ involves the Fibonacci constant (golden ratio). The solution of the trinomial octic $x^8-44x-33$ involves the Tribonacci constant. Kindly see this new [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598333/on-the-solvable-octic-x8-44x-33-0-and-the-tribonacci-constant).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using brute force approach I have found few others, such as
$$x^8+9x+9$$
$$x^8+75x+150$$

which factors over $\sqrt{-3}$ and $\sqrt{-15}$, respectively.

See https://sites.google.com/site/klajok/polynomials/x8-ax-b0

---

$\color{green}{Added:}$

Given pairs of rational numbers $\left(\alpha,\beta\right)$ such that $2\alpha^2+6\alpha+1=\beta^2$. Define the following parameters:

$$u=\frac{2\alpha+1-\beta}{4},\quad v=\frac{1-\beta}{8},\quad  w=\frac{\alpha}{8}\left(3\alpha-2\beta+3\right)$$
$$A=\frac{\alpha u}{2}\left(\alpha+1-4u\right),\quad  B=w^2 - \alpha v^2$$

then the following identity is satisfied:
$$x^8+Ax+B =\\ \left(x^4+\sqrt{\alpha}x^3+\left(-\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)x^2+\left(u\sqrt{\alpha}-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)x+\left(v\sqrt{\alpha}+w\right)\right)\\
\left(x^4-\sqrt{\alpha}x^3+\left(\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{2}+\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)x^2+\left(-u\sqrt{\alpha}-\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)x+\left(-v\sqrt{\alpha}+w\right)\right)$$

Let exclude the pairs $\left(\alpha, \beta \right) \in \left\{ \left(0, -1\right), \left(0, 1\right), \left(1, 3\right) \right\}$ for which trinomials degenerate to the simpler form where $AB=0$.

Observations:
If $\sqrt{\alpha}$ is not a rational number then the corresponding octic trinomials are irreducible and solvable. Otherwise the trinomials are still solvable but they are not irreducible.

Notes:

1. All the $\left(\alpha, \beta \right)$ pairs can be easily enumerated:
   $$\left(\alpha, \beta \right) \in \left\{ \left( \frac{2q+6}{q^2-2}, \frac{q^2+6q+2}{q^2-2} \right) : q \in \mathbb Q \setminus \lbrace -3, 4 \rbrace \right\}$$
   Excluded values $q=-3$ and $q=4$ correspond to the degenerate cases $(0, -1)$ and $(1, 3)$, respectively. The remaining degenerate case $(0,1)$ corresponds to the value $q$ at infinity (I found this "subparameterization" using the following Philip Gibbs' answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1905148).
2. Examples and preliminary conjectures related to this parameterization is available under the same page: https://sites.google.com/site/klajok/polynomials/x8-ax-b0 .

---

I searched for more examples of $C_2 \wr A_4$ and $C_2 \wr S_4$ for $x^8+ax+b$ and the only ones for integer $|a|,|b| \leq 100000000$ are:

$C_2 \wr A_4$:
$$x^8+64x+112=x^8+16(4x+7)$$

$C_2 \wr S_4$:
$$x^8-44x-33=x^8-11(4x+3)$$
$$x^8+768x+1344=x^8+3\cdot8^2(4x+7)$$
$$x^8+31740x+113735=x^8+5\cdot23^2(12x+43)$$
$$x^8-856251x-2023866=x^8-3^4\cdot31^2(11x+26)$$
$$x^8-5992704x-304129728=x^8-6^4\cdot34^2(4x+203)$$

Comment: The bounty will go to this post in about 24 hours. Since you mention your rep hinders you, then this should increase your rep to 100+ and allow you to participate more in the forum.

Comment: I've added an update about a second class of trinomial octics. Maybe you can find more examples for these as well?

Comment: Thank you very much Tito for the bounty! Regarding a second class of octics - currently I am aware of just one example with Galois group of its roots $C_2\wr A_4$, and 4 examples for $C_2\wr S_4$, so it might be a problem with guessing. Those examples are shown on my web page, so anyone can use them as a hint.

Comment: Checking out your page I found that you are interested in Klotski. I warmly recommend that you take a look [at another game evolved from Klotski](http://www.bricks-game.de/). As is possible when the tiles consist of bits as opposed to plywood, certain features become available. Over the years Andreas's game has come up with several tile/floor features that make the game more challenging and fun.

Answer (score 2):

A result of Harris [1] is that every monic palindromic polynomial of degree-8 can be factored into two monic palindromic polynomials of degree-4.

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) & = x^8 + ax^7 + bx^6 + cx^5 + dx^4 + cx^3 + bx^2 + ax + 1 \\
     & = (x^4 + px^3 + qx^2 + px + 1)(x^4 + rx^3 + sx^2 + rx + 1) \\
     & = x^8+x^7 (p+r)+x^6 (pr+q+s)+x^5 (p(s+1)+qr+r)+x^4 (2pr+qs+2)+x^3 (p(s+1)+qr+r)+ x^2 (pr+q+s)+x (p+r)+1
\end{align}
$$

Equating the coefficients:

$$
\begin{align}
a &= p+r \\
b &= pr + q + s \\
c &= p(s+1) + qr + r \\
d &= 2pr + qs + 2
\end{align}
$$

For the subset of degree-8 monic palindromic polynomials of the form

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) & = x^8 + 0x^7 + 0x^6 + 0x^5 + dx^4 + 0x^3 + 0x^2 + 0x + 1 \\
     & = x^8 + dx^4 + 1 \\
\text{we have }
0 &= p+r \\
0 &= pr + q + s \\
0 &= p(s+1) + qr + r \\
d &= 2pr + qs + 2
\end{align}
$$

We have the parametric solutions:

$$
r = 0 ∧ s = -q ∧ p = 0 ∧ d = 2 - q^2, \\
r = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{q} ∧ s = q ∧ p = -\sqrt{2} \sqrt{q} ∧ d = q^2 - 4 q + 2, \\
r = -\sqrt{2} \sqrt{q} ∧ s = q ∧ p = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{q} ∧ d = q^2 - 4 q + 2. \\
$$

Note that all of the above are parametrized on $d$.

On similar lines, we can factor the monic quartic palindromic polynomials into two monic quadratic palindromic polynomials each and then use the quadratic formula to get the roots.

**References**

[1]: J. R. Harris, "96.31 Palindromic Polynomials," The Mathematical Gazette, vol. 96, no. 536, p. 266–69, 2012. https://doi.org/10.1017/S0025557200004526