# On solvable high-degree trinomials like $x^9+3x^4-4$

Tags: galois-theory, radicals

Given $a,b \in \mathbb Q$ and $ab \neq 0.\,$ Let us consider trinomials $x^n+ax^k+b,\,$ with integers $n > k$, $n > 8$, and $gcd(n,k) = 1$.

Questions:

1. Do you know examples of *reducible* and solvable other than the following ones?
   $$x^9+19x+20 = \\ \left(x+1\right) \left(x^4-2x^3+2x^2-4x+5\right) \left(x^4+x^3+x^2+3x+4\right)$$
   $$x^9+80919x+495720 = \\ \left(x^3+6x^2+27x+72\right)\left(x^6-6x^5+9x^4+36x^3-27x^2-1458x+6885\right)$$
   $$x^9+3x^4-4 = \\ \left(x-1\right) \left(x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+4\right)$$
   $$x^{10}+297000000x-1846800000 = \\ \left(x^4-60x^2-300x+5400\right)\left(x^6+60x^4+300x^3-1800x^2+36000x-342000\right)$$
2. Are there any ***irreducible*** and solvable examples?

Notes:

1. If $x^n+ax^k+b$ is solvable then $1+ax^{n-k}+bx^n$ is too. For example $x^9+19x^8+25600000000$ can be obtained from $x^9+19x+20$. So we can focus only on values $ k < \frac{n}{2} $.
2. Similar questions for $n=8$ and $n=7$ were already asked:

- [On solvable octic trinomials like $x^8-5x-5=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054945/on-solvable-octic-trinomials-like-x8-5x-5-0)
- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146769/is-there-an-irreducible-but-solvable-septic-trinomial-x7axnb-0

3. The latter link contains the answer that there exist only finite number of solvable irreducible trinomials for $n=7$ and $n>8$. But there is no explicit example shown.
4. Details of how I found the mentioned nonic and decic trinomials are available on: https://sites.google.com/site/klajok/polynomials/reducible .
5. I have checked that for $8 < n < 17$ and integer $|a|,|b| \leq 100000$ there is no solvable irreducible trinomials.

Comment: +1. The $x^9+3x^4-4$ is beautiful. Its octic factors over $\sqrt{-3}$.

Comment: The closest irreducible but solvable nonic I found is the quadrinomial, $$6^4\, x^9 - 30x^2 - 10x - 5 =0$$ which results from eliminating $u$ between, $$ 6x^3 + 6u x^2 - 2(3u^2 + 3u - 5)x + u = 0\\6u^3 - 10u + 5 = 0.$$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII An update related to solvable polynomials of high degrees. I hope you will find that useful:
- irreducible solvable trinomials - no progress despite quite exhaustive searching - status: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NAWxqsDy2zHHuu7oK2YsaSi9iq90TjQV5vKRHNqU6-w
- (almost always) irreducible solvable nonic quadrinomials: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxrbGFqb2t8Z3g6NTYwMDk4NGZmODZlZTU1
- reducible solvable 10th quadrinomials: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxrbGFqb2t8Z3g6NmYyOWRkMTY5MGE3MDI1Ng

Comment: Thanks for the note, klajok.