# Find four rational numbers $~\frac{p}{q}~$ with $~\left|\sqrt 2 - \frac{p}{q}\right| \le \frac{1}{q^2}~$

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

> Find four rational numbers $~\frac{p}{q}~$ with $~\left|\sqrt 2 - \frac{p}{q}\right| \le \frac{1}{q^2}~$

Is there a way to find such numbers?

The only one I can think of is $~p = 1, ~q = 1~$ and I thought maybe if I could convert $~\sqrt 2~$ to it's nearest rational that would help but it didn't.

Comment: just a guess: continued fraction expansion

Comment: Try solving Pell's equation $q^2-2p^2=1$.

Comment: Possibly related: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555147/rational-solutions-of-pells-equation)

Comment: apparent I'm supposed to use the Dirichlet's approximation to solve it

Comment: How does solving Pell's eq help?

Comment: There is no "nearest rational to $\sqrt 2\,$".

Comment: @DylanY You may ignore the advice about Pell’s equation if it is beyond your course material.  Why haven’t you tried using Dirichlet’s approximation if that’s what you’re supposed to use?  Your question mentions nothing about it.

Comment: I didn't realize we were supposed to use Dirichlet's till I went over the course material so far and noticed the similarity

Answer (score 2):

If $p,q\in \Bbb N$ then $$|p^2-2q^2|=1\implies$$ $$\implies |\frac {p}{q}-\sqrt 2\,|\cdot |\frac {p}{q}+\sqrt 2\,|=|\frac {p^2}{q^2}-2|=\frac {|p^2-2q^2|}{q^2}=\frac {1}{q^2}\implies$$ $$\implies |\frac {p}{q}-\sqrt 2\,|=\frac {1}{q^2}\cdot \frac {1}{|\frac {p}{q}+\sqrt 2\,|}\le\frac {1}{q^2}\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}<\frac {1}{q^2}.$$

E.g. $(p,q)\in \{(1,1),(3,2),(7,5),(17,12)\}.$

Comment: There is a theorem that if $x$ is an irrational real then there are infinitely many pairs $(p,q)$ of integers satisfying $|x-p/q|<1/(q^2\sqrt 5\,)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Calculate some values $q\cdot \sqrt{2}$ and choose those close to an integer. For instance, the first $100$ multiples with $10$ decimals are 
$$
1.414213562, 2.828427125, 4.242640687, 5.656854249, 7.071067812, 8.485281374, 9.899494937, 11.31370850, 12.72792206, 14.14213562, 15.55634919, 16.97056275, 18.38477631, 19.79898987, 21.21320344, 22.62741700, 24.04163056, 25.45584412, 26.87005769, 28.28427125, 29.69848481, 31.11269837, 32.52691193, 33.94112550, 35.35533906, 36.76955262, 38.18376618, 39.59797975, 41.01219331, 42.42640687, 43.84062043, 45.25483400, 46.66904756, 48.08326112, 49.49747468, 50.91168825, 52.32590181, 53.74011537, 55.15432893, 56.56854249, 57.98275606, 59.39696962, 60.81118318, 62.22539674, 63.63961031, 65.05382387, 66.46803743, 67.88225099, 69.29646456, 70.71067812, 72.12489168, 73.53910524, 74.95331881, 76.36753237, 77.78174593, 79.19595949, 80.61017306, 82.02438662, 83.43860018, 84.85281374, 86.26702730, 87.68124087, 89.09545443, 90.50966799, 91.92388155, 93.33809512, 94.75230868, 96.16652224, 97.58073580, 98.99494937, 100.4091629, 101.8233765, 103.2375901, 104.6518036, 106.0660172, 107.4802307, 108.8944443, 110.3086579, 111.7228714, 113.1370850, 114.5512986, 115.9655121, 117.3797257, 118.7939392, 120.2081528, 121.6223664, 123.0365799, 124.4507935, 125.8650071, 127.2792206, 128.6934342, 130.1076477, 131.5218613, 132.9360749, 134.3502884, 135.7645020, 137.1787156, 138.5929291, 140.0071427, 141.4213562$$

([Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) states that among the first $N$ integers of any number $\alpha$ there exists at least one $q\alpha$ that is close to an integer by less than $\frac{1}{N+1}$, so by less than $\frac{1}{q}$ )

So one can take $q=7$ or $99$,  or others.